# Saga is being called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

How to stop saga being called multiple times. Once i dispatched an action i received the result multiple times. i don't know what i'm missing here.

**Saga.js**

```
export function* watchRegisterUser() {
  yield takeLatest(REGISTER_USER, registerWithEmailPassword);
}

export function* watchLoginUser() {
  const logi = yield takeLatest(LOGIN_USER, loginWithEmailPassword);
}

export function* watchLogoutUser() {
  yield takeLatest(LOGOUT_USER, logout);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(watchLoginUser),
    fork(watchLogoutUser),
    fork(watchRegisterUser)
  ]);
}
```

When i put wrong credentials i get the response and notification is displayed, working fine for the first time. But when i change the credentials, i get notifications (multiple times). Even when state

**Reference**: [Same problem here](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/502)

I'm not sure what am i missing here.

Thanks

**Update**

```
function* loginWithEmailPassword({ payload }) {

  const { history } = payload;
  try {
    const response = yield call(loginWithEmailPasswordAsync, payload.user);
    console.log("login  :", response);
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      const loginUser = yield response.json();

        localStorage.setItem("access_token", loginUser.access_token);
        yield put(loginUserSuccess(loginUser));
        history.push("/");

    } else if (response.status === 400) {
      yield put({
        type: LOGIN_USER_FAILURE,
        error: "Email and Password are wrong!"
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAILURE, error: "Something went wrong!" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you dispatch the actions that trigger the sagas?

Comment: @azundo thanks. I have updated the code. Have a look.

Comment: @Gigabyte did you get the solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you could try debounce to get around this, in the example below I debounce repeated actions withing a 500ms window.

```js
function* createAutocompleteLists(action) {   
  const state = yield select()
  if (!state.users.loaded && !state.users.loading) {
    yield put(getUsers())
    yield take([GET_SUCCESS, GET_FAIL])
  }

  yield call(parseAutocomplete, state.couchdbSavedSearch.current_share_with, state)
}

function* createAutocompleteForwardLists(action) {
  const state = yield select()
  if (!state.users.loaded && !state.users.loading) {
    yield put(getUsers())
    yield take([GET_SUCCESS, GET_FAIL])
  }

  yield call(parseForwardAutocomplete, state.forward.current_forward_to, state)
}

function* debounceCurrentShareWith () {
  yield debounce(500, [GET_SUCCESS, SET_CURRENT_SHARE_WITH, SPACE_SET_CURRENT_SHARE_WITH], createAutocompleteLists)
}

function* debounceCurrentShareWithForward () {
  yield debounce(500, [GET_SUCCESS, FORWARD_SET_CURRENT_FORWARD_TO], createAutocompleteForwardLists)
}

export default function* usersSagas() {
   
  yield spawn(debounceCurrentShareWith)
  yield spawn(debounceCurrentShareWithForward)
}
```